# How to add '~' sign to a returned nvarchar value?

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I am trying to add a '`~`' sign between two columns in SQL Server:

```
SELECT CODE + '~' + NAME FROM TEST_TABLE
```

It should return '`CCC~NNN`' but it displays a `newline` instead of '`~`'. How can I fix this?

Comment: Just executed your query on SQL Server 2008 and it worked for me!

Comment: it "displays" a newline. Displays where, how? Could it be that whatever is displaying the results interprets that character as a newline?

Comment: Do you get the newline if you replace the tilda with another character, such as `'-'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe theres a hidden new line char in one of the selected fields. Try this:

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(CODE + '~' + NAME, CHAR(13), ''), CHAR(10), '') FROM TEST_TABLE
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using different column names in the future.
For now, it might suffice to simply surround your column names with brackets:

```
SELECT [CODE] + '~' + [NAME] FROM TEST_TABLE
```

Works fine for me.